# Share x and y axis between subplots with map

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap, cartopy

I want to use `sharex` and `sharey` to sync `zooming` and `clicking` in two subplots.

Here's a simple code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature

proj = ccrs.LambertConformal(central_latitude=39,central_longitude=-95,
                            standard_parallels = (39, 39))

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))

ax1 = plt.subplot(2,2,1,projection = proj)
ax2 = plt.subplot(2,2,2,projection = proj,sharex=ax1, sharey=ax1)

ax1.coastlines()
ax2.coastlines()
ax1.add_feature(cfeature.STATES)
ax2.add_feature(cfeature.STATES)

ax1.set_extent([-100, -80, 20, 35], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax2.set_extent([-100, -80, 20, 35], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())

lon, lat = -85, 25

ax1.scatter(lon,lat,transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax2.scatter(lon,lat,transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

plt.show()
```

But, the range of map is different:
[image: original]
After a little moving by the `moving` tool, it's same!
 [image: move]

Here's another example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs


proj = ccrs.PlateCarree()

ax1 = plt.subplot(1,4,1,projection = proj)
ax2 = plt.subplot(1,4,2,projection = proj,sharex=ax1, sharey=ax1)
ax3 = plt.subplot(1,4,3,projection = proj,sharex=ax1, sharey=ax1)
ax4 = plt.subplot(1,4,4,projection = proj,sharex=ax1, sharey=ax1)


for ax in [ax1,ax2,ax3,ax4]:
    ax.coastlines()
    gl = ax.gridlines(crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(), draw_labels=True, color='gray', alpha=0.5, linestyle='--')
    ax.set_extent([-105, -75, 25, 50], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())

plt.show()
```

And, the result looks strange:

[image: example_2]

Comment: Oh I don't think cartopy axes actually understand `sharex` and `sharey`; if they do that might be coincidentally.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I think it actually works. Just the beginning is something wrong. After moving, it's same. You can check the update.

Comment: Actually I can't reproduce the issue when running the code. For me the plots are in sync from the start.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I add another example. Could you check that? The version of cartopy is 0.17.0.

Comment: [This is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVxzB.png) of the new code for me. I'm using cartopy 0.16.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's related to the version of `matplotlib`.
After updating to `3.0.2`, it works fine now.